# How to add pylint for Django in vscode manually?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have created a Django project in vscode. Generally, vscode automatically prompts me to install pylint but this time it did not (or i missed it). Even though everything is running smoothly, I am still shown import errors. How do I manually install pytlint for this project?

Also,in vscode i never really create a 'workspace'. I just create and open folders and that works just fine.

ps. Im using pipenv. dont know how much necessary that info was.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you must active your venv at the first then install pylint (pip install pylint)

In vscode: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then type linter (choose "python:select linter") now you can choose your linter (pylint)

I hope it helps you